# changing a specific character and occurence from user input

Tags: python, replace

I'm currently studying python development, one of my tasks has asked me to change the last word, and occurrence of it from a user input sentence.

I have tried the replace function and using the index(:-1)but it just doesn't work.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

the question is as follows.

ask a user to input a sentence.
replace the last character of the sentence with "@"
eg:if user inputs "how do you do"
answer would be:h@W d@ y@u D@

Comment: What specifically have you tried? The example does not match the assignment text, since the **last vowel of each word** should be replaced, something very much different than "last character of the sentence".

Comment: You should post the code you tried, so we can help. StackOverflow is not for doing homeworks from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

there is more complete, pythonic, pretty version of it but to stay simple:

```py
string_of_input = input()
last_char = string_of_input[-1]
modified_string = "".join(["@" if c == last_char else c for c in string_of_input])
```